# Excel / VBA If Countif Function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying to automate my Sheets in Excel.

I don't care if the solution works in vba or as a Excel function.

I want following:

If Row A contains specific word, copy neighbour cell in Row B to Cell C ( in another sheet )

What I already have :

```
 Sub Kopieren()
 Dim Zelle As Range
 Dim i%
  i = 7


  For Each Zelle In Sheets("AufgabenListe").Range("B8:B12")
  If Zelle <> "" Then
  Zelle.Copy
  Sheets("Mikro-RACI").Cells(i, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

 End If


 Next
 End Sub
```

The above only copies it. Wheter Row A has specific text or not. How can i Append a conditions (if Row A contains specific text) ?

Comment: VLOOKUP will do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("search text here",AufgabenListe!A8),AufgabenListe!B8),"")`

in column C